# MockServer SAPUI5 Connection

Tags: javascript, mocking, sapui5

I'm trying to get my data from a mockserver and i've done it like in [this tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bae9d90d2e9c4206889368f04edab508.html) but i can't apparently reach the mockserver.

In the console is this error:

> http://localhost:56141/destinations/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/ItemTypes?$skip=0&$top=100
>   404 (Not Found)

and

> The mock data for entity set "ItemTypesSet" could not be loaded due
>   to wrong format!

mockServer.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/util/MockServer"
], function (MockServer) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        init: function () {
            // create
            var oMockServer = new MockServer({
                rootUri: "/destinations/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"
            }); 
            var oUriParameters = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters();
            // configure
            MockServer.config({
                autoRespond: true,
                autoRespondAfter: oUriParameters.get("serverDelay") || 1000
            });
            // simulate
            var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("myApp.localService");
            oMockServer.simulate(sPath + "/metadata.xml", sPath + "/mockdata");
            // start
            oMockServer.start();
        }
    };
});
```

`metadata.xml` is also be there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="model">
            <EntityType Name="Items">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ItemsID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ItemsID" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>
                ...
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ItemTypes">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ItemTypesID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ItemTypesID" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="Items" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <NavigationProperty FromRole="From_ItemTypes" Name="ItemsSet" Relationship="model.ItemTypesItems" ToRole="To_Items"/>
            </EntityType>
            <Association Name="ItemTypesItems">
                <End Multiplicity="1" Role="From_ItemTypes" Type="model.ItemTypes"/>
                <End Multiplicity="*" Role="To_Items" Type="model.Items"/>
            </Association>
            <EntityContainer Name="default" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet EntityType="model.Items" Name="ItemsSet"/>
                <EntitySet EntityType="model.ItemTypes" Name="ItemTypesSet"/>
                <AssociationSet Association="model.ItemTypesItems" Name="ItemTypesItemsSet">
                    <End EntitySet="ItemTypesSet" Role="From_ItemTypes"/>
                    <End EntitySet="ItemsSet" Role="To_Items"/>
                </AssociationSet>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

My mockServer.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Walkthrough - Test page</title>
        <script
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                "myApp": "../"
            }'>
        </script>
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                sap.ui.require([
                    "hdc/localService/mockserver",
                    "sap/m/Shell",
                    "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"
                ], function (mockserver, Shell, ComponentContainer) {
                    mockserver.init();

                    new Shell({
                        app : new ComponentContainer({
                            height: "100%",
                            name: "myApp"
                        })
                    }).placeAt("content");
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing any network traffic if you're using the mock-server. The mock-server should detect requests that would usually go to a service. Once it detects these requests it should step in, formulate an answer and return that answer instead. The original request will not be executed. It seems however, that your mockserver is not setup. Have you made the changed in webapp/test/mockServer.html as suggested in the tutorial? And are you sure you are running the mockServer.html instead of the index.html when you launch your app in mockServer mode?

Comment: I've edited my question and added the mockserver.html. I can't see any error. It's exactly like the demo but my app uses the network and tries to connect to the service. :-(

Comment: How do you instantiate your ODataModel? Does the URI in the model setting match with the `rootUri` from the mock server?